# SVG to GeoJSON conversion - incorrect render

Tags: openlayers, geojson, svg

I have a vector image in SVG format.(without georeferences)

I am trying to display it using OpenLayers to display properties of different polygons in it.

I tried converting it to GeoJSON but the resulting render appears to be stretched (ratios are not preserved).

Is there a transformation or a map projection that I am missing  or recreating a GeoJSON from scratch the only relevant choice?

Comment: If there's no georeferencing in the SVG where in the world does it end up in OpenLayers? Can you show us what it looks like in an SVG viewer and on a map? Can you share the file or part of it?

Comment: OpenLayers doesn't require GeoJSON, that's only one option.

Comment: if you have an idea of where your polygons are on earth, you may try Bender plugin for qgis, which helps you affine (georreference) vectors such as svg